# NGINX: using variables in "auth_pam"

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I'm using the `auth_pam`-module in NGINX to authenticate users for a specific location and want to catch a folder-name into a variable while this variable should be shown on the headline of `auth_pam`.

Is that possible?

```
location ~ /testfolder/(\d+)/(\S+)/ {
  auth_pam                "folder1 is $1 and folder2 is $2";
  auth_pam_service_name   "nginx";
}
```

Currently the banner is shown as "**folder1 is $1 and folder2 is $2**" using *www-servers/nginx-1.10.0*